# How to properly position list of images in a clipped div

Tags: css, css-position

Here is my simple css/javascript image slider;

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show_image(idx)
{
    if(!slider)
        return;

    slider.style.left = "-" + ((idx - 1) * 422) + "px";
}
</script>
<style>

div, img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.slideshow-mask{
    width: 422px;
    height: 155px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow-image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 5486;
    height:155px;
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.slideshow-image-container img {
    width: 422px;
    height:155px;
}

#slideshow-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#slideshow-menu li {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-mask">
<div class="slideshow-image-container" id="slider">
<img src="frame1.png"/>
<img src="frame2.png"/>
<img src="frame3.png"/>
<img src="frame4.png"/>
<img src="frame5.png"/>
<img src="frame6.png"/>
<img src="frame7.png"/>
<img src="frame8.png"/>
<img src="frame9.png"/>
<img src="frame10.png"/>
<img src="frame11.png"/>
<img src="frame12.png"/>
<img src="frame13.png"/>
</div>

</div>
<ul class="slideshow-menu" id="slideshow-menu">
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(1)">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(2)">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(3)">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(4)">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(5)">5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(6)">6</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(7)">7</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(8)">8</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(9)">9</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(10)">10</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(11)">11</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(12)">12</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_image(13)">13</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Above code seems to work initially, however, as one gets to further images, images doesn't align properly in clipped area. I think it is supposed to work because I am clearing all margins, paddings and borders on all divs and images. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left` to the `img` style, it will eliminate the margin between the images

**OR**

Add `display: flex` to the `#slider` container.